# Any way to get notified when a inputable box is actived in windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, input, hook

In Android/IOS os, once a inputable box is clicked, the input method will be invoked automatically.

Now I have a similar demand on Windows os. We want to get the event when any inputable-box is clicked. I have investigated some softwares which own this function and they can work well most of the time execept it may miss rest of the time but which we can tolerate.

I have tried some method. Such as using spy++ to watch the event generated when a inputable-box is clicked, but i cannot find any clue.

Then i try to hook some API about IME followed:
`ImmGetCompositionFontW ImmAssociateContextEx`

`ImmGetCompositionFontW`  works well most of time, but it has seriously False Positives.

I think the key is still to hook, but i cannot decide which api to hook

can anyone help me? PS: forgive my poor English.

Comment: [WinEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/what-are-winevents) allow you to do that. Though this question reads like it's asking about a proposed solution rather than the *problem* it's ultimately trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, an "inputable box" will normally be something like an edit control or possibly a Rich text control.

In any case, it will normally be a window of some sort, and in Windows, when a window receives the "input focus", its owning code will receive a `WM_SETFOCUS` message. So, if you need to do something when a particular control receives input focus, you'll normally want to handle `WM_SETFOCUS` for that control.

Comment: I look up `WM_SETFOCUS` with spy++, and found only native windows GUI controls will received `WM_SETFOCUS ` when focused. Some self-drawn GUI framwork such as Qt which has only one hwnd as a whole, their inputable-boxs won't receive 'WM_SETFOCUS ' when focused.

Comment: @LOMO: Yeah, if you want to support things with...spitefully bad designs, you're going to have to jump through flaming hoops to do it. IMO, it's usually better not to though.

Comment: Much to everyone's (?) despair, native Win32 UIs have long ceased being the norm. Outside of native UI wrappers (MFC, ATL/WTL, wxWidgets, and Windows Forms in part), it seems the *"We can do better!"* fallacy has taken over. Qt being the odd one out, that cannot seem to decide on what to do (native up to Qt3, with a return to sanity planned for Qt6). WPF, though, and whatever *"Metro"* is called this week have departed. Same goes for virtually all browsers. Not supporting what everyone (?) is using today isn't good enough a selling point today.